# ssh tunnel between two servers

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I am creating the ssh tunnel using ssh -D 1080 hasinet from hasnoinet host, when from another session on hasnoinet do: curl google.com:1080. It doesn't work.

Comment: probably related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053453/how-to-connect-to-internet-through-a-remote-server-via-ssh-connection

Comment: Look up a tool called "sshuttle"

Comment: Your commands are confusing, they have nothing to do with your needs. If I understand your needs correctly, please refer to Jesse_b's Link

Comment: I am doing ssh -D 1080 hasinet   from hasnoinet, when from hasnoinet do: curl google.com:1080. It doesn't work

Comment: After `ssh -D 1080 hasinet`, the `hasnoinet` system will have a SOCKS proxy at `localhost:1080`. At that point, `curl --socks5-hostname localhost:1080 google.com` should work. With or without specifying the proxy, `curl google.com:1080` will always fail because Google does not have any services in port 1080 and won't respond.